# ng2-modal's Modal is closing unexpectedly

Tags: angular

I have used [ng2-modal](https://github.com/pleerock/ng2-modal) for my modal.

When I call the following function I have created:

```
deleteCommitee(id:number){
  var length = this.addnewCommitee.length;
  for(var i = 0;i<length;i++){
    if(id == i){
     this.addnewCommitee.splice(i,i);
    }
  }
}
```

the modal disappears. I have replicated the situation in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4iRPL13fLPn0HrSD7TG9?p=preview).

In the plunker example please click the button to trigger the modal open and then click on cross button below 'email id 0' input field

Actually through this function I want to remove an element from `addNewCommittee array`.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the click from propagating through the DOM.
[Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fDRvV5CLPRBwu9y9Q07d?p=preview)

**deleteCommitee**

```
deleteCommitee(id:number,event:any){
    //event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    for(var i = 0;i<this.addnewCommitee.length;i++){
      console.log(this.addnewCommitee[i]);
      if(id == this.addnewCommitee[i].count){
        //console.log(this.addnewCommitee[i]);
        console.log(this.addnewCommitee.splice(i,1));
      }
    }
  }
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="close_icon_div cursor_pointer" (click)="deleteCommitee(newCommitee.count,$event)" >
```